# Структура БД международные автобусные рейсы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Пытаюсь сделать БД покупки билетов на автобусные рейсы.

Дайте совет в проектировании системы бронирования-покупки билета на автобусы

- Таблица **flight** хранится информация о рейсах.
- **bus** - информация о автобусах и количеством мест в нем.

Меня интересует:

1. Как хранить информацию об остановках(место отправки,место
   прибытия),так же между ними могут тоже быть остановки,как это
   продумать?
2. Как формировать цены на билет между станциями.
3. Хранения мест автобуса. Добавить возможность выбора номера места,
   при покупке билета.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Изменено
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужна таблица Станции/Остановки + таблица связки для нее с таблицей Flight, примерно такой структуры (FlightId, ИдОстановки, [Порядковый номер по маршруту], [Время прибытия], [Время отправления]), соответственно в таблице Flight не нужны колонки From и To, да пожалуй, и date_start, date_end тоже не нужны

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Гляньте вторую картинку,я немного изменил диаграмму

Comment: Если у вас действительно SQL Server - поменяйте тип колонок на с VARCHAR на NVARCHAR - иначе получите приключения с русскими буквами :)

Comment: И еще, если это действительно SQL Server, поменяйте `TIMESTAMP` на более подходящий тип. В SQL Server `TIMESTAMP` предназначен для совсем других целей. :)

Comment: Оставьте метку реально используемой СУБД. Ненужную метку уберите.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл подумать о разных таймзонах на разных остановках, о продаже багажных мест и о хранении данных при сторнировании/возврате билета. А также о предзаказе/бронировании. Ну и вообще о структуре данных цен (формировать цены между остановками, скорее всего, придётся не программно, а на основании эмпирики — спроса, пассажиропотока, загрузки рейсов etc.). А ещё, раз/если вы делаете систему _продавца билетов_, вам надо работать со многими перевозчиками и для каждого иметь свои условия — процент с продажи etc.